# Trying to get Start Time and End Time of a meeting in a Table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, max, min, reportbuilder

I need to get a Start Time and End time of a video chat meeting, depending on when the video started and ended. Meaning I would like to get the Start time based on the first initialized load chat window, and the End Time based on the last video end chat, all by the same user ID. Also would need to extract the date from the Times, so i can get a date of the meeting.  Below is my code and data coming out.  Hoping someone can provide more help.

So i would like to get one row that shows:
Video Date, Start Time, End Time, and Session Length.

```
select distinct originalChatSessionID,
    logID,
    logType,
    logDetail,
    applicationUserID,
    --videoDate,
    min(receivedDateTime) as 'Start Time',
    max(receivedDateTime) as 'End Time'



  FROM iclickphrDxvideolog 
    --inner join iclickphrDxvideo v
    --  on l.originalChatSessionID = v.MeetingSessionID

  where originalChatSessionID = @MeetingSessionID
    and (logType = 'Initialize-Load Video chat Window' or logType = 'Video Chat-End Chat')
  group by originalChatSessionID, /*videoDate,*/receivedDateTime, logID, logType, logDetail, applicationUserID
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you want to be GROUPing on receivedDateTime. If you only want one record per session, you'll need to not use the logType, logDetail, logID, userID.

Comment: Adding to  Hannover Fist's comment. You need to think "What columns identify a single chat?" If it's only `originalChatSessionID` then that's all you need to group by. If this does not help, edit your question and show the results you would expect to see based on your sample data above.

Comment: Please provide sampe data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get one row that shows: Video Date, Start Time, End Time, and Session Length, this should do it:

```
select originalChatSessionID, 
       CONVERT(DATE, min(ReceivedDateTime)) as VideoDate, 
       CONVERT(TIME, min(ReceivedDateTime)) as StartTime,
       CONVERT(TIME, max(ReceivedDateTime)) as EndTime,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min(ReceivedDateTime), max(ReceivedDateTime)) as SessionLength
from iclickphrDxvideolog
where originalChatSessionID = @MeetingSessionID
group by originalChatSessionID
```

I've assumed your SQL dialect is SQL Server and that you are happy to show the session length in minutes :-)

Comment: Perfect, that worked great.  Only thing i am having issues with now is converting the time to 12 hour time and AM/PM.

Tried using CAST but having issues working it in.  Can you provide some assistance with this?

Comment: @Lern2LveWithIt - the conversion to display a date or time should be done at the report level and not in the SQL. You can use `=FORMAT(Fields.StartTime.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy tt")` or set the `Format` property of a text box to `MM/dd/yyyy tt`.

Comment: @HannoverFist I have tried formatting it on the report level.  It just keeps giving me #Error when running the report. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Lern2LveWithIt - I just noticed it's converting the StartTime field to TIME `CONVERT(TIME, min(ReceivedDateTime))` which seems unneccesary. Try just using `min(ReceivedDateTime) as StartTime` to see if that works.

Comment: You can use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CONVERT(TIME, min(ReceivedDateTime)),100) as StartTimeAMPM` to get the 12 hour time with AM/PM

Comment: @HannoverFist, ReceivedDateTime is a DateTime field. `CONVERT(TIME,...` is used to remove the Date part as required by the question.